# Converting polyline to presence absence raster in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, binary

I have a polyline that I am converting to a raster in arcpy. This is occuring within a loop and at each iteration I change the processing environment to a different area of interest. In this case it is a specific polygon (like below)

```
whereClause = '"FID" = ' + str(poly.FID) # Create a clause to select only the current record
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(shapefile, "currentPolygon", whereClause)        
arcpy.env.extent = "currentPolygon"
```

At each iteration I would like to create a raster where cells containing the polyline are given a value of 1 and cells without polyline are given a 0 within the bounds of the env.extent.

What is the key to creating the 0 values?

Does it come from the arcpy.env.nodata parameter?

I can make the conversion in my loop but cannot quite get the binary format I am envisioning.

```
arcpy.FeatureToRaster_conversion("roadsLayer", "VALUE", "roadsGrid.tif",)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the  [help files for ArcMap](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/How_to_change_NoData_cells_to_a_value/009z000000ms000000/), the link states how to do it procedurally, simply check the IsNull and Con statement links for code examples.  I also think you can "not" the isnull expression shown in the IsNull link, but I have no way of testing it now

Comment: This requires Spatial Analyst?

Comment: @klewis, yes as indicated in the IsNull and Con help sections

Comment: Reclass might work as well, i.e. NO DATA will get 0

Comment: From these answers/comments it sounds like it cannot be done by changing the env.extent value and it must be done with another reclass or IsNull/Con step